# Buscar coincidencias (intersección) entre dos DataFrames y guardarlas en un tercer DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos DataFrames Pandas sin cabeceras:

> ```
> df1:
>                                              0      1      2  3
> 0                     Globotruncana intermedia   67.7   65.9  D
> 1                    Globotruncana mayaroensis   66.7   65.0  D
> 2                         Acarinina acarinata    59.2   55.5  S
> 3            Globigerina soldadoensis angulosa   51.8   41.3  S
> 4      Acarinina aquiensis (Loeblich & Tappan)   59.2   52.3  S
> 5                      Globorotalia bullbrooki   50.4   38.5  S
> 6                     Globigerina coalingensis   56.8   46.5  S
> ...
>
> df2:
>                                                    0
> 0                                 Gr. peripheroronda
> 1      Neogloboquadrina opima Bolli subsp. continuosa
> 2                                  Gr. Peripheroacuta
> 3   Globigerinoides quadrilobatus (d'Orbigny) subs...
> 4                                 Acarinina acarinata
> 5            Globorotalia scitula (Brady) praescitula
> 6                          Globigerina baroemoenensis
> ...
> ```

`df1` tiene 600 filas y `df2` es variable. `df2` siempre sería alimentado a partir de un Excel con datos diferentes y `df1` seria una tabla maestra. La idea es poder buscar que filas de `df2` coinciden con las filas de `df1`. Lo datos que coincidan deben irse guardando en un nuevo DataFrame junto con los datos de las demás columnas de `df1`.

En este ejemplo el único que coincide es `"Acarinina acarinata"` por lo que me gustaría que el tercer DataFrame se viera así:

> ```
>                                              0      1      2  3
> 0                         Acarinina acarinata    59.2   55.5  S
> ```

¿Puede alguien colaborarme diciéndome cómo lo hago o en dónde buscar lo que necesito?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) en modo `inner` sobre la primera columna, (`"0"`)

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data1 = StringIO(
"""\
                                             0      1      2  3
0                     Globotruncana intermedia   67.7   65.9  D
1                    Globotruncana mayaroensis   66.7   65.0  D
2                         Acarinina acarinata    59.2   55.5  S
3            Globigerina soldadoensis angulosa   51.8   41.3  S
4      Acarinina aquiensis (Loeblich & Tappan)   59.2   52.3  S
5                      Globorotalia bullbrooki   50.4   38.5  S
6                     Globigerina coalingensis   56.8   46.5  S
"""
)

data2 = StringIO(
"""\
                                                    0
0                                  Gr. peripheroronda
1      Neogloboquadrina opima Bolli subsp. continuosa
2                                  Gr. Peripheroacuta
3   Globigerinoides quadrilobatus (d'Orbigny) subs...
4                                 Acarinina acarinata
5            Globorotalia scitula (Brady) praescitula
6                          Globigerina baroemoenensis
"""
)

df1 = pd.read_table(data1, sep="\s{2,}", engine="python")
df2 = pd.read_table(data2, sep="\s{2,}", engine="python")
intersection = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='0')
```

> ```
> >>> intersection
>                         0        1       2    3
> 0     Acarinina acarinata     59.2    55.5    S
> ```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias por enseñarme FJSevilla !!!